# Como forcar download de arquivos mpdf usando Ajax

Tags: ajax, mpdf

Estou tentando fazer o download de arquivos pdf usando a biblioteca [mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/).

Chamando a página php no navegador ela funciona normalmente.

**Exemplo:**

```
require_once 'mpdf/mpdf.php';

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$boleto = '<h3>Boleto</h3>';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($boleto);

$mpdf->Output('teste.pdf',"D");
```

Agora se eu tento chama-la de uma página html usando o ajax o retorno dela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como chamo do Ajax:**

```
var salvarBoleto = function(parcelas) {
  $.ajax({
    url: boletoUrl,
    data: {
      "acao": "salvarBoleto",
      "parcelas": parcelas
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.warn("mostrar msg de erro");
    }
  });
};
```

Normalmente eu chamo uma nova aba para emissão do pdf, mas neste caso gostaria de faze-lo na página do ajax.

Comment: Você pode postar o trecho do JS que chama o ajax?

Comment: @Laerte pronto :)

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, lembra de ter resolvido isso ?

Comment: @WagnerFilho se eu me lembro bem eu tive que abrir o arquivo em um iframe para fazer o download na mesma pagina, ai eu criei um iframe invisivel e atulizei o src dele.